# Alphabetizing 5 Words / No Array (Java)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, alphabetized

I am stuck (sort of), and I can't seem to see a way to finish this code.  I have to design a program without Arrays (My Teacher is terrible and does not allow arrays -_-) The goal of the program is to take in 3 - 5 words, and use alphabetize them. I have made a program that works with 3 words, but am perplexed as how to make a program that alphabetizes 5 words. Any help would be appreciated. Note, My Question is Different from the other Alphabetize w/o Array questions as it is involving 5 words, not 3, 2, or any other amount. Thank you for your help! Code is Below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Alphabetize
{    int nums = 1;
    int x = 0;
    String input01 = "";
    String input02 = "";
    String input03 = "";
    String input04 = "";
    String input05 = "";
    int compare01, compare02, compare03, compare04, compare05;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Alphabetize a = new Alphabetize();
        a.getInput();
        a.comparer();
    }

    public void getInput()
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many words do you want to input");
        nums = kb.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter " + nums +" words");
            if(nums == 3)
            {
                input01 = kb.next();
                input02 = kb.next();
                input03 = kb.next();
            }

            else if(nums == 4)
            {
                input01 = kb.next();
                input02 = kb.next();
                input03 = kb.next();
                input04 = kb.next();
            }
            else
            {
                input01 = kb.next();
                input02 = kb.next();
                input03 = kb.next();
                input04 = kb.next();
                input05 = kb.next();
            }

    }

    public void comparer()
    {
        if (nums ==3)
        {        
            compare01 = input01.compareTo(input01);
                System.out.println(input01 + compare01);

            compare02 = input01.compareTo(input02);
                System.out.println(input02 + compare02);

            compare03 = input01.compareTo(input03);
                System.out.println(input03 + compare03);
        }

        else if (nums ==4)
        {

            compare01 = input01.compareTo(input01);
                System.out.println(input01 + compare01);

            compare02 = input01.compareTo(input02);
                System.out.println(input02 + compare02);

            compare03 = input01.compareTo(input03);
                System.out.println(input03 + compare03);

            compare04 = input01.compareTo(input04);
                System.out.println(input04 + compare04);
        }

        else
        {        
            compare01 = input01.compareTo(input01);
                System.out.println(input01 + compare01);

            compare02 = input01.compareTo(input02);
                System.out.println(input02 + compare02);

            compare03 = input01.compareTo(input03);
                System.out.println(input03 + compare03);

            compare04 = input01.compareTo(input04);
                System.out.println(input04 + compare04);

            compare05 = input01.compareTo(input05);
                System.out.println(input05 + compare05);
        }
    }

   }
```

Comment: Note : I cannot use any methods like treeSort() or anything like that

Comment: (Apart From Scanner)

Comment: *Alphabetize* - does this mean `sort`?

Comment: So you say you made something that alphabetizes 3 words. Can you find the first of the 5 words, the last of the 5 words, and then apply your program to the remaining which will be the middle 3?

Comment: That is such a good idea Jermey!!! Thank you so much! If you want, you can post that as a response, an I can accept it